# Change "oo" to "00" in a string using some loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Need to hep to change multiple characters in a string using some loop without built-in functions in PHP.

```
<?php
       $givenString = "School";
       $i=0;
    while($givenString[$i]){
        $i++;
        if($givenString[$i] == o){
        $givenString[$i] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    echo $givenString;
    ?>
```

Result: Sch0ol
Required Result: Sch00l

Comment: Note: You need to quote strings. The un-quoted `o` only works because you're using an old, end-of-life version of PHP and have error reporting turned down/off.

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you. Actually, I am doing practice in an online editor https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_intro

Comment: @Bilal So what's the output for `ooooo`?

Comment: @nice_dev using above script output is: o0ooo

Comment: @Bilal Not that. What is your expected output?

Comment: @nice_dev given input is School. And expected outpoot is Sch00l. Means I want to replace multiple characters

Comment: @Bilal For input `ooooo`, do you expect the output to be `0000o` ?

Comment: @nice_dev yes. Please help with code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your loop logic is out of order. Feed in the string `"ooooo"` and you'll get `"o0ooo"` out. It skips the first letter because the first thing you do is move the index ahead, and it stops after the first replacement because you're testing the character that you just replaced, and `"0"` [type-juggles](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to boolean as `false`.

Move `$i++` to the *end* of the loop and you'll get `"00000"`, but also `Warning: Uninitialized string offset 6`. This is because you're relying on the error to break the loop. You need to bound the loop on the `length` of the string, not the content.

So:

```
$givenString = "oooooo";
$i=0;
$c=strlen($givenString);
while($i<$c){
    if($givenString[$i] == 'o'){
        $givenString[$i] = 0;
    }
    $i++;
}

echo $givenString;
```

or we can condense that with `for` loop:

```php
$givenString = "oooooo";
for( $i=0, $c=strlen($givenString); $i<$c; $i++ ){
    if($givenString[$i] == 'o'){
        $givenString[$i] = 0;
    }
}

echo $givenString;
```

For completeness, the un-quoted `o` in your post only works because pre-8.0 PHP assumed that unquoted constants were just "oopsies" meant to be strings and replaced them with their string equivalent, issuing a Notice like `Notice: Use of undefined constant o - assumed 'o'`, which can potentially have serious side-effects.

This error also indicates that you're using a version of PHP that is no longer supported, and you should ensure that you are writing code on a [supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions).

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, you are replacing all `o` to `0` which is off-track with respect to replacing `oo` to `00` and also skipping the current `o` at hand doesn't make sense. Also, as already pointed out, matching a string with a string is better than comparing with just `o` directly.

---

You can instead match `o` with `o` and check if string contained a previous `o` or not. If it did, mark both previous and current location as `0`, or else, leave it as is. Since you didn't wish to use inbuilt functions, you can use null-coalescing operator(??) to check with the length of the string as well.

```
<?php

function modify($string){

  for($i = 1; ($string[$i] ?? false) !== false; ++$i){
    if($string[ $i ] === 'o' && $string[$i - 1] === 'o'){
      $string[ $i ] = $string[$i - 1] = '0';
    }
  }
  
  return $string;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yhx3ra6z)